# Ext JS Combobox inside a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

In reference with [Combobox inside a grid](http://www.walkingtree.in/forums/showthread.php?439-Combobox-inside-a-grid-setting-default-value) example. I was able to do this in my page. problem is, when i change the value in one of the combobox, the rest of the combobox in the same row also change, they all have the same value.

I'm using only a javascript and basic html and ext js with this. I'm using ext sandbox (ext4).

any help?

```
if(columnData != undefined){
        for (var i = 0; i < columnData.length; i++) 
        {

            var storedata = [];     
            for(var gr = 0;gr < gridData.itemData[0][0].length;gr++){           
                storedata.push([(gr + 1),gridData.itemData[0][0][gr]]);         
            }

            var comboRenderer = function(combo) {                    
                return function(value) {
                    alert(value);
                    alert(combo.valueField);
                    var idx = combo.store.find(combo.valueField, value);                        
                    if ( idx < 0 ) {
                        idx = 0;            
                    }                       
                    var rec = combo.store.getAt(idx);               
                    return rec.get(combo.displayField);                  
                  };
            };

            fields.push({name:columnData[i].name});             
            columns.push({text:columnData[i].name, width: 140, menuDisabled: true, sortable: false, align: 'center', forcefit: true, 
                columns: [{                 
                    text: 0,
                    draggable: false,
                    hideable: false,
                    flex: 1,
                    width: 140,
                    dataIndex: columnData[i].name,
                    menuDisabled: true, 
                    sortable: false, 
                    align: 'center',
                    editable: true,
                    renderer: comboRenderer(new Ext4.form.ComboBox({
                        id: i.toString(),
                        typeAhead: true,
                        triggerAction: 'query',
                        mode: 'queryMode',
                        autoSelect : false,
                        autoShow : true,
                        emptyText : 'Select item',
                        store: new Ext4.data.ArrayStore({
                            fields: ['id' + i, 'description' + i],
                            data : storedata
                            }),
                        displayField:'description' + i,
                        valueField: 'id' + i,
                        forceSelection: false
                    })),
                    editor: new Ext4.form.ComboBox({
                        id: i.toString(),
                        typeAhead: true,
                        triggerAction: 'query',
                        mode: 'queryMode',
                        autoSelect : false,
                        autoShow : true,
                        emptyText : 'Select item',
                        store: new Ext4.data.ArrayStore({
                            fields: ['id' + i, 'description' + i],
                            data : storedata
                            }),
                        displayField:'description' + i,
                        valueField: 'id' + i,
                        forceSelection: false
                    })
                }]
            });         
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all share the same store. You need to create a copy of the store for every combobox.

Comment: Hi. I did this. please see update in my question. But still same behavior

Answer (score 0):

somehow, i just need to clear my cache for my updates to work. tnx @A1rPhun